# Running 'bundle install' ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to run a bundle install and I always seem to get the same error 'Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory'

If someone could explain a possibility of why I may be getting this it would be very helpful

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure you execute the command in the root folder of your project? And is there a `Gemfile` present?

Comment: Does the directory you are running it in contain a Gemfile?

Comment: Yes there is a gemfile and its a terminal file is that what should be there?

Comment: Please confirm: There is a `Gemfile` (with an upcase `G`). *Not* `gemfile` (downcase) like your wrote in your comment.

Comment: yeah sorry it does have an uppercase G, forgot to specify that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm which file bundler is trying to use as its `Gemfile`, try this:

```
bundle exec ruby -e "puts ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']"
```

To make sure you don't have a setting that's causing bundler *not* to use the `Gemfile` in your current (or a parent) directory, try this:

```
bundle config Gemfile
```

Comment: Unfortunately the first command repeats the same error 'Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory'

Comment: It also says that with the second command I haven't configured a value for Gemfile

Comment: `touch Gemfile` will ensure that the `Gemfile` exists by creating an empty one if it can't be found.  Give that a try and then re-try the first command.

Comment: Thank you so much everything is working perfectly now! :)